# Revolution of tractrix

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, inverse, inverse-function

Consider the tractrix

$$c:(0,\frac{\pi}{2})\rightarrow(0,1)\times(-\infty,0),\quad c(t)=\Big(\sin(t),\cos(t)+\log\circ\tan(\frac{t}{2})\Big)$$

I want to write the parametrisation of its surface of revolution like this:

$$F:(-\infty,0)\times(0,2\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,\quad F(t,\varphi)=(r(t)\cos(\varphi),r(t)\sin(\varphi),t)$$
This means I want to find a function $s:(-\infty,0)\rightarrow(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, such that
$$\cos(s(t))+\log\circ\tan(\frac{s(t)}{2})=t$$

Then I would define $$r:(-\infty,0)\rightarrow(0,1),\quad r(t)=\sin(s(t))$$

I hope this makes sense so far. How could I determine the function $s$?

Comment: Why are you trying to find $s(t)$ explicitly? You can do all the computations you need without an explicit arclength parametrization.

Comment: Because I want to show that $K=-1$, where $K$ is the gauss curvature.

Comment: Oh, I guess, I just have to find a parametrisation and calculate it from that, right? I mean: Any parametrisation would be fine, right?

Comment: So I could just take the parametrisation $F:(0,\frac{\pi}{2})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,\quad F(t,\varphi)=(\sin(t)\cos(\varphi),\sin(t)\sin(\varphi),\cos(t)+\log\circ\tan(\frac{t}{2}))$

Comment: Yup. Arclength parametrization is basically good only for theory. Otherwise, you work around it, e.g., with the chain rule.

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try. Thank you for your comments!